# git format-patch output files don't have commit messages

Tags: git

I have two recent commits in a branch I'm working on, both with commit messages that show up in the log.  When a run

```
git format-patch -2 --signoff
```

the created patch files are named according to their commit messages and have the correct subject, but the commit message blocks at the top of the files don't have the commit messages.  For example:

```
From <git hash> Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: <my email>
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 16:31:46 -0400
Subject: [PATCH 1/2] <full commit message>


Signed-off-by: <my name, my email>
---
<beginning of patch>
```

I can't find any `git format-patch` switches that control if the commit message is printed in the body of the patch email.  The commit messages should be printed in the space before the Signed-off line.  How do I get git to behave normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my commit messages only contained one-line summaries.  When running `git format-patch`, the first paragraph of each commit message is placed in the subject of the email .  Only the following paragraphs are added to the body of the email.  The solution was to write [proper commit messages](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html).